# What's the significance of pomegranates?

Tags: word-study, exodus, layers-of-meaning

I'm curious about the significance of pomegranates - *[rimmown](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H7416&t=KJV)*.

While this word occurs 32 times in 25 verses in the Hebrew concordance of the KJV, we can limit the scope of this question to Exodus.

In Exodus 28:33 (KJV)

> And beneath upon the hem of it thou shalt make **pomegranates** of blue, and of purple, and of scarlet, round about the hem thereof; and bells of gold between them round about:

In Exodus 28:34 (KJV)

> A golden bell and a **pomegranate**, a golden bell and a **pomegranate**, upon the hem of the robe round about.

In Exodus 39:24 (KJV)

> And they made upon the hems of the robe **pomegranates** of blue, and purple, and scarlet, and twined linen.

In Exodus 39:25 (KJV)

> And they made bells of pure gold, and put the bells between the **pomegranates** upon the hem of the robe, round about between the **pomegranates**;

In Exodus 39:26 (KJV)

> A bell and a **pomegranate**, a bell and a **pomegranate**, round about the hem of the robe to minister in; as the LORD commanded Moses.

What do pomegranates represent?

Comment: Other than being a highly regarded, beautiful ornament, we are not told.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A gotquestions.org article [What is the significance of pomegranates the Bible](https://www.gotquestions.org/pomegranates-in-the-Bible.html) discusses the characteristic of the fruit, the decoration motif in priestly garments and the temple, and possible symbolisms:

- Jewish traditions that the pomegranate's 613 seeds correspond with the 613 laws in the Torah
- Fruitfulness, blessing, and prosperity (Num 13:23, Deut 8:8), the trees as a nation's financial and material wealth (Joel 1:12, Hag 2:19)
- Represents Israel: battered on the outside like the peel but able to bless others from within
- Describes the loveliness of the bride (Song of Solomon 6:11, 7:12, 8:2, 4:3)

Answer (score 2):

The following is transcribed from a [sermon](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Comm/mcgee_j_vernon/eBooks/golden-bells-and-pomegranates.cfm) by J. Vernon McGee

> Now the thing that interests me are those golden bells and pomegranates.
>
> And beneath upon the hem of it thou shalt make pomegranates of blue,
> and of purple, and of scarlet, round about the hem thereof; and bells
> of gold between them round about: A golden bell and a pomegranate, a
> golden bell and a pomegranate, upon the hem of the robe round about.
> (Exodus 28:33, 34)
>
> Pomegranates speak of fruit, if you please. We are told today that the
> blossom of the pomegranate is like a five—pointed star. We’ve all
> heard of the six—pointed star of David, but very few of us have heard
> of the five—pointed star of Solomon. May I say that it is quite
> interesting that the pomegranate blossom is like that. And then we are
> told concerning these golden bells:
>
> And it shall be upon Aaron to minister: and his sound shall be heard
> when he goeth in unto the holy place before the LORD, and when he
> cometh out, that he die not. (Exodus 28:35)
>
> Now these two things, pomegranates and golden bells, speak of sweet
> sounds and fragrant fruit. There is something to hear and something to
> taste. May I say that the bells speak of profession; the pomegranates
> speak of practice. The bells speak of the calling of the believer; the
> pomegranates speak of the conduct of the believer. The bells speak of
> vocalization. Paul says, “I therefore, the prisoner of the Lord,
> beseech you that ye walk worthy of the vocation wherewith ye are
> called” (Ephesians 4:1).
>
> We have a vocalization and then we have a vocation down here, and the
> calling and the vocation should correspond.

Answer (score 0):

Asking about the symbolism of pomegranates in the Bible is like asking about the symbolism of lotus flowers in Egyptian religion. There are many interesting and interrelated interpretations which could easily fill a book. Here, I wanted to give readers additional information as an introduction to this culturally significant fruit, whose cultivation in Mesopotamia dates to the 4th millenium BC<sup>1</sup>

[image: Early depiction of a procession around pomegranate tree]

### As a symbol for beauty, sexuality, and fertility

Throughout the ancient near east, the pomegranate, due to its abundance of seeds, was a symbol of feritility<sup>2</sup>. From its pleasing taste and red color, it was a symbol of sexuality and beauty (Song of Solomon 4.3 and 6.7) and thus as an *object of desire*.

From the *Song of the Gracious Gods* in Ugarit<sup>4</sup>:

> The two wives are the wive[s of El],
>
> the wives of El, and forever.
>
> He stooped: their lips he kissed.
>
> O, how sweet were their lips,
>
> as **sweet as pomegranate**[s];
>
> from kissing came conception,
>
> from embracing, impregnation.

From the Babylonian Talmud:

> The Gemara continues: One who wishes to see something
> resembling the beauty of Rabbi Yoḥanan should bring a new, shiny
> silver goblet from the smithy and **fill it with red pomegranate seeds**
> [partzidaya] and place a diadem of red roses upon the lip of the
> goblet, and position it between the sunlight and shade. That luster is
> a semblance of Rabbi Yoḥanan’s beauty.  Bava Metzia 84a:7

From the Theological Dictionary of the Old Testament<sup>5</sup>:

> The tree or its fruit is often depicted on monuments, ornaments,
> pendants, and the like, although the secondary literature does not
> always clearly distinguish pomegranates from apples, quinces, and
> poppy heads.5 The pomegranate also appears frequently in the literary
> productions of the eastern Mediterranean, Mesopotamia, Iran, Urartu,
> Greece, and the Aegean. Its symbolic significance has frequently been
> noted. In the ancient Near East as well as the Greco-Roman world, the
> pomegranate was a symbol of fertility or an aphrodisiac; it also
> symbolized life. Not every picture or mention of a pomegranate,
> however, should be considered symbolic. The pomegranate is
> occasionally associated with so-called dying-and-rising deities.

#### Related: Temptation and Forbidden Fruit

So it also became a common symbol of *temptation* and *forbidden fruit*. Some traditions have the pomegranate as the fruit in the Tree of the Knowledge of good and evil<sup>3</sup>(although other traditions call it a different fruit). Similarly in Greek mythology, Perspephone ate a single pomegranate seed and was thrown into the underworld.

During the festival of Sukkoth (Feast of Tabernacles), the walls of the sukkah were decorated with each of the seven fruits, including pomegranates but it was forbidden to eat them.

From the Tosefta<sup>6</sup>:

> G. [If] one hung up in it [as decoration] nuts, peaches, pomegranates,
> bunches of grapes, and wreaths of sheaves of corn, it is valid.
>
> H. One should not eat of any of these, even on the last day of the Festival.

There is a charming story of the pomegranate as a forbidden fruit in the Talmud, (translation from [sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.81b.1?lang=bi)):

> Every time Rabbi Chiya bar Abba fell upon his face (in the Tachanun
> prayer) he used to say, ‘The Merciful save me from the Yetzer Ha'Rah.
> One day his wife overheard him. ‘Let me see,’ she reflected, ‘it is so
> many years that he has separated from me: why then should he say
> that?’ One day, while he was studying in his garden, she adorned
> herself with a scarf and strolled in front of him. ‘Who are you?’ he
> asked. ‘I am Cheruta, and have returned today,’ she replied. He
> desired her. Said she to him, **‘Bring me that pomegranate from the
> uppermost branch.’ He jumped up, went, and brought it to her**. When he
> re-entered his house, his wife was firing the oven, whereupon he went
> and sat in it. ‘What is this?’ she asked. He told her what had
> happened. ‘It was I,’ she told him; but he paid no heed to her until
> she gave him proof. ‘Nevertheless,’ said he, ‘my intention was evil.’
> That righteous man fasted all his life, until he died from that very
> death.

### As one of the Seven Fruits, thus a symbol of Christ, the Holy Spirit, and the Church

There are seven fruits or "seven seeds" in the promised land, outlined in Deutoronomy 8.7-8:

> For Yahweh your God is bringing you to a good land with streams of
> water, springs and underground water, welling up in the valleys and in
> the hills, to a land of **wheat** and **barley** and **vines** and **fig** trees and
> **pomegranate** trees, a land of **olive** trees, olive oil and **honey**; (LEB)

(The "honey" is understood to be honey from dates, so dates are the seventh.)

These seven seeds play a special role in the Old Testament:

- Only these seven could be raised as a heave offering as "first fruits". See the Jerusalem Talmud<sup>7</sup>:
  *[A] They may not bring firstfruits [from any produce] other than [the] seven kinds [for which the land of Israel was noted, i.e., wheat, barley, grapes, figs, pomegranates, olives used for oil, and dates for honey (Deut. 8:8)]*
- These seven seeds *are* the first fruit. Whenever you read a reference in the Law about the "first fruit", *it is talking about these seven seeds* (unless it is a metaphor, e.g. Christ as the first fruit or something else "as" the first fruit.).
- The harvest began on the day after Sabbath in the week of passover. The first day, Sunday, was the Feast of First Fruits. The Israelites set aside the first fruits for God and could not eat of them (another reference to the *Forbidden Fruit* symbol) until after the counting of the Omer was complete. During the counting of the Omer, each day a prayer needed to be said until this 7 week period of gathering in was complete, after which all the first fruits were dedicated to God as a heave offering on the 50th day, Pentecost.
- On the Feast of Pentecost, these 7 seeds were carried in a special procession and raised to God as a heave offering in front of the entire congregation. Thus they are symbols of the 7 fruits of the Spirit.
- Christ was crucified on the Day of Preparation (Thursday), rested in the grave on the Sabbath, and rose on Sunday, the Feast of First Fruits, as the first fruit of all those who will be resurrected: *But now Christ has been raised from the dead, the first fruits of those who have fallen asleep (LEB)* (1 Cor 15.20). Thus the pomegranate, as a first fruit, is a symbol of Christ, or at least it is part of the collection that pre-figures Christ.
- But the first fruit is also a symbol of the *Spirit* of Christ *within believers*: *Not only this, but we ourselves also, having the first fruits of the Spirit, even we ourselves groan within ourselves while we await eagerly our adoption, the redemption of our body.* Romans 8.23. And thus of believers: *But we ought to give thanks to God always concerning you, brothers dearly loved by the Lord, because God has chosen you as first fruits for salvation by the sanctification of the Spirit and faith in the truth.*  2 Thess. 2.13 (LEB) See also Rev 14.4

#### related: use in heave offerings and the festivals

There is much more symbolism of pomegranates in the feasts. For example,

- the paschal lamb could only be roasted on a stick of pomegranate wood - no other wood could be used. From the Jerusalem Targum<sup>8</sup>:

> [A] How do they roast the Passover offering?
>
> [B] They bring a spit of pomegranate wood,
>
> [C] and stick it through [the carcass] from the mouth to the buttocks.
> [...]
>
> [I:1 A]  Why [use a spit made] of pomegranate [wood]?
>
> [B]      Said R. Hiyya bar Ba, “All trees drip moisture and that of pomegranate does not drip moisture.”
>
> [C]      With what situation do we deal? If with moist [wood], even that of pomegranate drips. If with dry [wood], even all trees do
> not drip.
>
> [D]      Rather [teach] thus [as the reason in C:] All trees are dry outside and moist inside. Pomegranate is dry outside and dry
> inside. [Hence using the latter type of wood insures that no moisture
> would drip and no inadvertent boiling take place.]

Note that the pomegranate wood was considered the exact opposite of the fruit. It was viewed as *dry* and *bitter* wheras the fruit was *moist* and *sweet*. This dichotomy also carries symbolism as it refers to the pomegranate as fruit of the knowledge of *good* and *evil*, something that is to be desired and obtained but also to be abstained from. This dichotomy is present in the bad wood versus the good fruit.

From the Jerusalem Talmud again, the wood was considered bad:

> [I:1 A]      It is written, “The fruit of a goodly tree” (Lev. 23:40).
>
> [B]      This refers to a tree the fruit of which is good, and the
> wood of which also is good.
>
> [C]      And what sort of tree is that? It is the etrog.
>
> [D]      If you say that it refers to a pomegranate, **its fruit is
> good but its wood is not good.**

And it was considered the most bitter wood, as one of the potential trees to make the bitter water sweet (from [sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/297081.20?lang=bi&p2=Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber%2C_Beshalach.18.2&lang2=bi)):

> AND THE LORD SHOWED HIM A TREE. What was it?61Tanh., Exod. 4:24;
> Mekhilta de Rabbi Ishmael, Wayassa‘ 1; Exod. R. 50:3. R. Joshua says:
> It was an olive tree; R. Nehemiah says: A willow tree. Some say: The
> roots of a fig tree; and others say: **The roots of a pomegranate,
> since there is nothing as bitter as those.**

So you see this dualism which again echoes the "knowledge of good and evil", as the pomegranate is both the sweetest and the most bitter, with the bitter sometimes able to make sweet, and the sweet sometimes forbidden. The dry bitter wood that the paschal lamb is roasted on versus moist, the sweet fruit that is offered to the Lord in Pentecost. Also related to the eating of the bitter and sweet on Passover.

#### Related: as a symbol of Israel and thus the church

The traditional symbol of Israel is "vineyard" or promised land, but pomegranates are "metaphorically adjacent" to these, as pomegranates are made into wine similar to grapes, and the fruit of the pomegranates is often a synechdoche for the land in which it grows. We see

- Joel 1.11-12 the withering of the seven seeds is a metaphor for the barrenness of Israel.
- Song of Solomon 4.12-13, the "orchard of pomegranates" has been interpreted as a reference to Israel, as the beloved, or bride, is interpreted as Israel by rabbis<sup>10</sup> and as the Church or Body of Christ by Christians.
- In Haggai 2.19, the promised fruitfullness of pomegranates and the other 7 seeds is a metaphor for blessings and fruitfulless of Israel.

### As a symbol of mishpat: judgement, decison, law, regulation

Given the symbolism of the fruit of the knowledge of good and evil, e.g. deciding for yourself what is good and evil, it is no wonder that there are many associations with pomegranate and *mishpat*, the hebrew word glossed in the heading. To start, we can go back to the Song of Solomon 6.7:

*Your cheeks behind your veil are like halves of a pomegranate.* (LEB)

The word for "cheeks" here is *raqqah*, which is actual "forehed" or "temple". That didn't make sense to the translators so they wrote it as "cheeks" and made it plural, but a more faithful translation is found in the NICOT commentary<sup>9</sup>:

> ```
> Like a slice of pomegranate is your temple
>   behind your veil.
> ```

Traditionally, this verse was equated with *knowledge* and sometimes *mitzvot*. This was targummed<sup>10</sup> as:

*And the King, who was their head, was as full of precepts as a pomegranate,*

In the Talmud, this is often referred to as knowledge of the torah, precepts, or even mitzvot:

> If the golden altar in the Temple, which was only covered by gold the
> thickness of a golden dinar, stood for many years and the fire did not
> burn it, for its gold did not melt, so too the sinners of the Jewish
> people, who are **filled with good deeds like a pomegranate**, as it is
> stated: “Your temples [rakatekh] are like a split pomegranate behind
> your veil” (Song of Songs 6:7), will not be affected by the fire of
> Gehenna. And Rabbi Shimon ben Lakish said about this: Do not read:
> Your temples [rakatekh], but rather: Your empty ones [reikateikh],
> meaning that even the sinners among **you are full of mitzvot like a
> pomegranate;** how much more so should the fire of Gehenna have no power
> over them. ([Sefaria translation](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.19a.9?lang=bi))

There is a famous passage in the Talmud where a student of Rabbi Aher (who later became an apostate) defends studying under him because "ate the pomegrante but threw the peel away". Thus the fruit of the pomegranate is compared to knowledge acquired from the apostate rabbi.

> The Gemara relates: Rabba bar Sheila found Elijah the prophet, who had
> appeared to him. He said to Elijah: What is the Holy One, Blessed be
> He, doing? Elijah said to him: He is stating halakhot transmitted by
> all of the Sages, but in the name of Rabbi Meir He will not speak. He
> said to him: Why? He replied: Because he learned halakhot from the
> mouth of Aḥer. He said to him: Why should he be judged unfavorably for
> that? **Rabbi Meir found a pomegranate and ate its contents while
> throwing away its peel.** He said to him: Indeed, your defense has been
> heard above. (sefaria [translation](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.15b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

- Torah scroll covers are shaped like pomegranates (called *rimonim*) also continuing the association with knowledge.
- fruit in the old testament is also often interpreted as knowledge (e.g. Pr 25.11)
- By tradition the pomegranate has 613 seeds, corresponding to each of the 613 mitzvot<sup>11</sup>

### Conclusion

This is just a taste of the many meanings and symbols of the pomegranate. I hope this can start you on further reading.

### Notes

<sup>1</sup>  Abram, Mary. "The Pomegranate: Sacred, Secular, and Sensuous Symbol of Ancient Israel." Studia Antiqua 7, no. 1 (2009). https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/studiaantiqua/vol7/iss1/4

<sup>2</sup> Jacob, I., & Jacob, W. (1992). Flora. In D. N. Freedman (Ed.), The Anchor Yale Bible Dictionary (Vol. 2, p. 808). New York: Doubleday.

<sup>3</sup> Eisenberg, R. L. (2004). The JPS guide to Jewish traditions (1st ed., p. 696). Philadelphia: The Jewish Publication Society.

<sup>4</sup>Wyatt, N. (2002). Religious texts from Ugarit (2nd ed., p. 332). London; New York: Sheffield Academic Press.

<sup>5</sup> Mulder, M. J. (2004). רִמּוֹן. G. J. Botterweck, H. Ringgren, & H.-J. Fabry (Eds.), D. E. Green (Trans.), Theological Dictionary of the Old Testament (Revised Edition, Vol. 13, p. 505). Grand Rapids, MI; Cambridge, U.K.: William B. Eerdmans Publishing Company.

<sup>6</sup> Neusner, J. (2002). The Tosefta: Translated from the Hebrew with a New Introduction (Vol. 1 & 2, p. 568). Peabody, MA: Hendrickson Publishers.

<sup>7</sup> Neusner, J. (2008). The Jerusalem Talmud: A Translation and Commentary. Peabody, Massachusetts: Hendrickson Publishers.

<sup>8</sup> Neusner, J. (2008). The Jerusalem Talmud: A Translation and Commentary. Peabody, Massachusetts: Hendrickson Publishers.

<sup>9</sup> Longman, T. (2001). Song of Songs (p. 178). Grand Rapids, MI: Wm. B. Eerdmans Publishing Co.

<sup>10</sup> Braude, W. G., & Kapstein, I. J. (2002). Pĕsiḳta dĕ-Rab Kahăna: R. Kahana’s compilation of discourses for Sabbaths and festal days (2nd ed., p. 276). Philadephia, PA: Jewish Publication Society.

<sup>10</sup> Cathcart, K., Maher, M., & McNamara, M. (Eds.). (2003). The Aramaic BibleA: The Targum of Canticles. (P. S. Alexander, Trans.) (Vol. 17, p. 30). Collegeville, MN: The Liturgical Press.

<sup>11</sup> Eisenberg, R. L. (2004). The JPS guide to Jewish traditions (1st ed., p. 671). Philadelphia: The Jewish Publication Society.